# how can i play small music file when i tuch an image in android?

Tags: android

I am New to android, My task is to playing a small audio file when we touch an image?

Comment: Looking at your other questions, you really should be a good community member and vote on good answers, and pick one that works for you. That lets other people who come along know what worked.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your target API version there are a different ways of doing this.

Assuming you have something like this inside your layout xml file.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageThatWillPlaySound"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    androidL:onClick="playSound">
</ImageView>
```

Note `androidL:onClick="playSound"` which will run the function in your activity that matches the definition:

```
public void playSound(View v) {
}
```

Inside that function, you would use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) as xandy suggested.

Something like this

```
public void playSound(View v) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file);
    mp.start();
}
```

Where inside your assets folder you had a file called sound_file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play.